# GMP mpz_sizeinbase returns size 2 for 9 in base 10

Tags: c, gmp

I'm trying to use libgmp and I encountered something strange using mpz_sizeinbase. If I use a number which starts by base - 1 the size is one too big.

```
#include <gmp.h>
mpz_t n;
int main() {
    unsigned int base = 10;
    mpz_init_set_str (n, "90", base);
    mpz_out_str(stdout, base, n);
    printf(" has length %zu in base %d\n", mpz_sizeinbase (n, base), base);
}
```

when I run it:

```
$ gcc -g draft.c -o draft -lgmp && ./draft
90 has length 3 in base 10
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [kkk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32604910/586873) already explained the result of `mpz_sizeinbase`. However, if you want to obtain exact length in decimal base, you can convert it into character array with [`mpz_get_str`](https://gmplib.org/manual/Converting-Integers.html#Converting-Integers) and then use `strlen` from C Standard library (`<string.h>`):

```
printf(" has exact length %zu in base %d\n",
    strlen(mpz_get_str(NULL, base, n)), base);
```

Output:

```
90 has exact length 2 in base 10
```

There is one caveat though, for a negative number you may need to substract one, as string representation includes `-` sign.

Comment: Corner question: Can "-0" occur in `mpz_t`?

Comment: @chux: Not in current implementation of GMP. Both `+0` and `-0` are stored in the same manner, namely `_mp_size` field, that is responsible for storing sign is set to zero. See [16.1 Integer Internals](https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Internals.html#Integer-Internals) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

Note The last statement.

*the right amount of allocation is normally two more than the value returned by mpz_sizeinbase, one extra for a minus sign and one for the null-terminator.*

> size_t mpz_sizeinbase (mpz_t op, int base)
>
> Return the size of op measured in number of digits in the given base.
>   base can vary from 2 to 62. The sign of op is ignored, just the
>   absolute value is used. The result will be either exact or 1 too big.
>   If base is a power of 2, the result is always exact. If op is zero the
>   return value is always 1.
>
> This function can be used to determine the space required when
>   converting op to a string. The right amount of allocation is normally
>   two more than the value returned by mpz_sizeinbase, one extra for a
>   minus sign and one for the null-terminator.

[Similar question here worth looking at it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058222/number-of-digits-of-gmp-integer)